# Separar string y sólo quedarse con los enteros Python

Tags: python, string, split

Espero puedan ayudarme con esta duda de Python. Dispongo del siguiente string:

`st="MK325-0.50x1523"`

Me gustaría, que una vez separado el string, pudiese tan sólo quedarme con los enteros de ambos lados (los que están detrás de las letras en mayúscula y los que están detrás de x). Es decir, que el resultado para este caso fuese:

`(325,1523)`

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

`p=st.split("-")[0][2:5]+","+st.split("-")[1][5:9]`

Pero el resultado no es el que espero, ya que, aunque me devuelve los valores que quiero, me los devuelve así:

`"325,1523"`

A parte de esto, la forma en que lo hago, tan sólo me sirve para sacar los enteros de este string.
**¿Habría alguna manera de que fuese automático y me sirviese para sacar los valores enteros de cualquier string sin tener que especificarle los valores entre [ ] (como hago arriba) para cada caso concreto?**

Por ejemplo, si tuviese: `“PMJ12-1.25x36” o “K2-15.36x1”…`
Me devolviese:
`(12,36)` o `(2,1)` respectivamente.

Quedo atento. Gracias de antemano.

Saludos,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una solución usando la expresión regular `[A-Z](\d+).*x(\d+)` que reconoce una la primera secuencia de dígitos después de una letra y la segunda secuencia después de una letra `x`.

```
re.findall("[A-Z](\d+).*x(\d+)", st)
```

La función `re.findall` aplica dicho patrón sobre la cadena y devuelve una lista de tuplas con los valores extraidos.

```
[('325', '1523')]
```

De está lista sólo nos interesa la primera tupla, la que recorremos convirtiendo las cadenas a entero.

**Comprobación**

```
import re
ejemplos = ["MK325-0.50x1523", "PMJ12-1.25x36", "K2-15.36x1"]

for st in ejemplos:
    numeros = [int (x) for x in re.findall("[A-Z](\d+).*x(\d+)", st)[0]]
    print(st, numeros)
```

produce:

```
MK325-0.50x1523 [325, 1523]
PMJ12-1.25x36 [12, 36]
K2-15.36x1 [2, 1]
```

Comment: Gracias Candid Moe por tu respuesta. Todavía no domino mucho el tema de expresiones regulares, aunque se entiende muy bien tu explicación. Aprovecho para preguntarte: ¿Sería posible obtener el mismo resultado sin el uso de expresiones regulares y sin importar re. Por ejemplo, a través de condicionales o bucles...? Gracias

Comment: Si, es posible hacerlo sin expresiones regulares, pero es una lata. Requiere mucho código.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes probar con expresiones regulares por ejemplo:

```
import re

numbers = list(map(int,re.findall('\d+(?=-)|\d+$', st)))

print(numbers)
```

En este caso se busca en la cadena esto: `\d+(?=-)` o esto: `\d+$`. Que busque una cosa o la otra se indica mediante `|`.

En el primer caso busca una o mas repeticiones (`+`) de cualquier digito (`\d`, esto es lo mismo que `[0-9]`) seguido por un guion (`(?=-)`, esto se llama *lookahead assertion*).

El segundo busca una o más repeticiones de cualquier dígito (igual que en el ejemplo anterior) pero que este al final del texto (`$`).

Otra posible manera de hacerlo, ya que en tu texto parece que buscas cualquier número que esté a continuación de una letra:

"M**K**325-0.50**x**1523"

'PM**J**12-1.25**x**36'

'**K**2-15.36**x**1'

En este caso seria buscar cualquier digito (`/d`) que esté seguido de cualquier letra (`(?<=[a-zA-Z])`). O lo que es lo mismo, buscar `[a-z]` en el texto en minúsculas:

```
re.findall('(?<=[a-z])\d+', st.lower())
```

Con ambas expresiones te daría los números que buscas:

```
'MK325-0.50x1523'  -->  [325, 1523]
'PMJ12-1.25x36'  -->  [12, 36]
'K2-15.36x1'  -->  [2, 1]
```

Comment: Excelente expresión. Si pudieses ya indicar un poquito *por qué* funciona esa en concreto ya sería una respuesta genial.

Comment: Si, esa era mi intención, pero he tenido que dejar la respuesta a medias. Cuando vuelva a casa mi intención es explicarla.

Answer (score 2):

Es más fácil hacerlo con `re`, pero pongo una versión alternativa sin `regex`.

Mi propuesta es recorrer caracter por caracter e ir recogiendo todos los números. Cuando se encuentra un caracter no numero, se reemplaza por espacio.
NOTA: Es necesario recoger los caracteres punto porque si hay números a ambos lados, estos quedarían separados en dos enteros y la respuesta ya no sería correcta.

```
st = "MK325-0.50x1523"
st2 = ''
for c in st:
    st2 += c if (c.isdigit() or c == '.') else ' '
```

Hasta este punto la cadena st2 será:   `325 0.50 1523`

Ahora se hace un `st2.split(' ')`, que dará: `['', '', '325', '0.50', '1523']`
Finalmente se vuelve a recorrer la lista, se filtrarán los elementos que solo contienen números, eliminando todos los demás (vacíos o con punto) y se convierte a entero lo que sobre. Dicho eso en código y una sola expresión por comprehensión:

```
result = [int(x) for x in st2.split(' ') if x.isdigit()]
# [325, 1523]
```